# Get the next state of a generator in Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I initialized a generator in PyTorch with a manual seed. How do I obtain the current state/seed of the generator? For example, if I want to check the state in a loop, how can I do that? This is what I want to achieve:

```py
import torch

gen = torch.Generator("cpu").manual_seed(42)

for _ in range(5):
    # print the next state of the generator
```

PS: I tried to use `gen.seed()` but it gives different results on different runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.Generator.get_state`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Generator.html#torch.Generator.get_state) to retrieve the current state of the generator.

Per the docs:

> `get_state() → Tensor`
>
> Returns the Generator state as a `torch.ByteTensor`.
>
> **Returns:** A `torch.ByteTensor` which contains all the necessary bits to restore a Generator to a specific point in time.

You can pass the value you get from `get_state` to [`set_state`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Generator.html#torch.Generator.set_state) to restore the previous state of the generator.

Comment: `get_state()` is giving me the global state. I want the updated state at every iteration